# Empty Headers & Response Body when writing to Response Body

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When writing manually to the response body in the controller, some application do receive the Body & headers correctly. While other (older) application, do not receive any data.

e.g.:

```
public Task Index()
{
    ...
    HttpContext.Response.Headers["test"] = "Hello";
    HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(...);
}
```

While these same apps do receive a 'correct' response if I use a IActionResult

```
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    HttpContext.Response.Headers["test"] = "Hello";
    return Ok("My content");
}
```

I've tried adding Response.Body.Flush / Close & Dispose. That does not seem to help.

Is there something else I'm missing ?

I should add:

- asp.net core 2.2
- docker

Comment: what says the real http request sent to the older application?

Comment: The body and response headers are just empty

Comment: It's as if they were not sent / flushed

Comment: use the tool telerik fiddler to figure out what goes over the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that those old clients could not deal with unix line endings.
Adding dos line endings resolved the issue